# How do I assess the conservation of a protein function across different homologs, isoforms, biosimilars?

Tags: proteins, toxicology, homology

I am studying toxicology where the presence of a "toxic" function is more important (in context) than a protein's ancestry. After scanning the lit, homology modelling seems to be the best way to infer (via structural conservation of functional domains/motifs) whether a function has been conserved or a protein has a similar action to another. Based on this my questions are:

1. Is there a better term for "functionally similar" than homolog, isoform, or biosimilar? Homolog implies common ancestry which isn't always the case. Isoform doesn't include homologs which may be the case. Biosimilars is very much tied to pharmaceuticals, which I would prefer to avoid.
2. Does anyone have any recommendations for models that can indicate/estimate the functional similarity between proteins? I realize this is a long shot, but the closest I have found so far was CSM-Toxin, which predicts toxicity, but doesn't alone the comparison of multiple protein sequences.

Comment: All of your three alternatives are unsuitable and should not be used. Spell it out in full, although how similar is similar is the crux of the matter.